# Using Applescript to get the subject of an email - Not working as advertised

Tags: applescript, mail.app, email

I'm new to Applescript, trying to do a basic script that gets called from a mail Rule.

Im stuck on getting the subject. There doesnt seem to be one available.

```
using terms from application "Mail"
on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
tell application "Mail"
        repeat with aMess in theMessages
            try
                set subj to subject of aMess
                (*
                aMess has only one property, "contents"  =
                message 1 of mailbox "Incoming POP Messages" of account id "CD180EE3-9A52-4623-BBF0-F722556AF94A"

                *)
                if subj is "" then error
            on error errMsg
                (* errMsg is 
            osascript got an error: Can’t get subject of message 1 of mailbox "Incoming POP Messages" of account id "CD180EE3-9A52-4623-BBF0-F722556AF94A".
            clearly it cant get subject because it has only "contents" property
            How to get the actual email and it's values ?
            *)
                set subj to errMsg
            end try
            display dialog "The Subject is " & subj
        end repeat
    end tell
end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

So,

***How to get the actual email and it's values ?***

I thoguht that was automatic in the loop for each item.

Comment: Is this Mojave?  Because I say "set theSubject to the subject of theMessage" all the time, but I don't use Mojave.  Seems you're running into the enhanced security.

Comment: Good guess, but I'm on high Sierra 10.13.6. Mail is version 11.5 .